# What’s a good translation of “loomings”?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Moby Dick Chapter 1 is titled

> CHAPTER 1. Loomings.

probably an unconventional nominalisation of the verb “loom / looming”, indicating certain prospects appearing on the horizon, or foreboding something.

What is a good German translation of this word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Gutenberg you can find the English original version as well as a German translation

- [Moby Dick in English on Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-h/2701-h.htm#link2HCH0001)
- [Deutsche Übersetzung des ersten Kapitels von Moby Dick](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/melville/mobydick/chap001.html)

As you can see, the title of Chapter 1 is in English:

> CHAPTER 1. Loomings.

And in German:

> Erstes Kapitel

So, this doesn't help. But it shows how translators deal with this problem: They ignore it.

So, what do dictionaries say? My personal favorite is dict.leo.org, and it has a translation for [looming](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/looming):

1. **looming** - die Luftspiegelung pl: die Luftspiegelungen
   German *Luftspiegelung* is literally *"air mirroring".* (English translations of *Luftspiegelung* are *looming* and *mirage*) This means an optical reflection on a surface that is made of air. This happens when a layer of cooler air hovers above a layer of hot air. If it happens in a desert you call it *Fata Morgana,* but a *Luftspiegelung* can happen anywhere, also in the air above an ocean.
2. **looming [tech.]** - Einziehen der Kettfäden in Geschirr und Schaft
   This translation obviously has to do with weaving. The Englisch noun *loom* also means *»Webstuhl«* (*weaving loom, weaving machine*) in German. I'm not really familiar with the terminology of weaving, but [Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator) told me, that *»Einziehen der Kettfäden in Geschirr und Schaft«* is in English *»drawing in the warp threads into the harness and dobby«,* but I can't guarantee that this translation is correct. (At least it seems plausible to me.)

But I don't think that any of both translation fits really well as title for the first chapter of Moby Dick. So we need to find a better translation, maybe one that addresses the fact that the noun *looming* is a nominalization of the verb *to loom.* When you consult dict.leo.org again, you get these suggestions (among others):

- **aufragen** (to loom, to tower)
- **sich abzeichnen** (to loom, to be on the horizon, to be in the offing, to become apparent, to emerge)
- **drohend auftauchen** (to appear minatory, to emerge threatening, to arise impendingly)
- **sich in der Ferne auftun** (to appear in the distance, to loom from afar)
- **undeutlich sichtbar werden** (to become indistinctly visible, to become apparent faintly)

This list describes better, what *looming* could be, but packing it into just one German noun is difficult. Here are some words and phrases that came into my mind:

- drohendes Unheil (threat of disaster, threatening fate)
- Vorahnung (foreshadowing, premonition, precognition)
- Schemen (shadows, silhouettes, shadowy figures)
- Anzeichen (signs, indications)

But maybe it is really the best, to just use *»Erstes Kapitel«* as title.

Comment: That’s a very good answer! I think I prefer Schemen or Luftspiegelung because they both have a similarly poetic, imagistic quality. And the connotation in the book is not negative, as in threatening; merely hinting at the development of new opportunities.

Answer (score 3):

The German chapter is called [Schemen](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Schemen). [Kapitel 1 | Schemen | Hanser E-Library](https://www.hanser-elibrary.com/doi/10.3139/9783446300026.001)

*Loom/Loomings* is difficult to translate as a single word. Certrain prospects appearing on the horizon is a good fit for *Schemen* (see above). Foreboding something could be translated as [*Omen*](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Omen) or simply [*Anzeichen*](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Anzeichen). You can even go full mythical and say *ominöse Schemen* but that almost seems like a bit of overkill, does carry both sentiments though.

Comment: *»Schemen«* is not so bad, but where did you find it? I only found a translation where the title of chapter 1 is just »[Erstes Kapitel](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/melville/mobydick/chap001.html)«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I included a link

Comment: I own a translation published by Ueberreuter 1977, tranlated by Ilona Paar (and branded as "Neubearbeitung" - new adaptation). Its first chapter bears the heading "Die Ferne des Meeres lockt".